# Is the (anti)derivative of an even complex valued function odd, and vice versa?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm not sure how much content I can put for a relatively straightforward question, haha. But, I'm attempting to prove something about even and odd functions and integrals in Complex Analysis, and I was curious as to if it is true that the (anti)derivative of an even complex valued function is odd, and vice versa, as it is for reals (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be true given $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is differentiable:

$f(z) = -f(-z) \implies f'(z) = -(- f'(-z)) = f'(-z)$ (ie. derivative of an odd function is even)

and

$f(z)=f(-z) \implies f'(z) = - f'(-z)$ (ie. derivative of an even function is odd).